# Active diode not allowing full voltage through

Tags: mosfet, diodes, igbt

I'm working on a transformer active battery balancing circuit and have it working except, due to the diode voltage drop on the secondary, I need an alternative.

Since the battery cell voltage is 4 V, a 1 V drop is 25% efficiency loss and obviously will have huge imbalance issues. I thought about adding another winding on the transformer to increase the voltage but would instead like to add a active diode.

I tried the following circuit design but it's not working. The IGBT is not turning on fully and only allowing 1.5 V through. I am using a RJP30E2 which has a saturation voltage of 1.7 V. The transformer is running at 120 kHz.

I have very little experience and understanding of electronics and started this project a few weeks ago.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV6G7e.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Why can't you use MOSFETs a la H-bridge?

Comment: Please show the circuit that doesn't work. The link shows a circuit with a transformer and diodes

Comment: All the mosfets I looked into have a too high of a gate voltage

Comment: heres the correct link: http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWECAstIIEwDZsHZNJ8MAOZSZEFAZmQFMBaMMAKAHcRNMVwBOTKijJh+Udp26cUFatWxSKkFmAS8q2HoTIoNnAlCjQIYeKfjiUQvgJ08RApR1vX1myGUchZ87jLlesMSddTH1nakClACcvfwibXXiDVgA3CTtRLk1pZKoKJEVDBHFvBUEyXzEAey8QXQppXjUYUzxsTF5qXhQEajBMJGxoHgoBWmoWIA

Comment: MOSFETs can be found with "logic level" gate voltages ([logic level MOSFET](https://www.radwell.com/en-US/Buy/SIEMENS/SIEMENS/A5E33962008)) which can be quite low.  Study the datasheets.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site :-) I'd edited your question's presentation to make it more readable for the community, including burying your circuit's webpage as a hyperlink. I'd tested it and the hyperlink works, it's the same as the hyperlink you posted in your comment. Following that, please could you edit your question to show the circuit on the page of the question, not just by hyperlink. Thanks.

Comment: hello how do I embed the circuit into the post? I noticed other posts had the circuit embedded from falstad. When I try to click embed circuit it forces me to use circuitlab

Comment: hello im unable to find a logic level mosfet that can operate below 4v. The battery voltage fluctuates and can go as low as 2.5v. All the logic level mosfets I found have a RDS voltage of 4.5 or higher. Theres so many mosfets though so maybe im missing something. I have no clue what to search for and have studied many datasheets. Is there any reason a IGBT cant do the job?

Comment: ive redid the schematic with circuit labs and embeded it into the question

Comment: How much current does the transistor need to pass?  We can show you how to interpret a MOSFET datasheet based on this info.

Comment: at least 15 amps of current

Comment: ok, that is going to be rough then.  That is a lot of current for a logic-level MOSFET.  Perhaps schottky diodes are a solution.

Comment: also had others suggest shottky diodes and currently thats my only solution I can see. 0.5v is better than 1v but I would still like to aim for a better solution.

Comment: Fair enough.  Check my answer below, all hope is not lost for MOSFETs.

Answer (score 2):

Although 15 A is a lot of current for a logic-level MOSFET, all hope is not lost.

Take, for instance, a [DMN2011](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMN2011UTS.pdf).  Let's look at the datasheet.

First things first, lets check out the Electrical Characteristics on Page 2 and see what the "On Characteristics" looks like.  We want to scrutinize the "Static Drain-to-Source On-Resistance":

[image]

This is looking promising!  Let's investigate further.

On page 3, figures 1 and 3:

[image]

Figure 1 shows us that current is pretty linear with voltage at 15 A with Vgs of 1.8 V and higher.

Figure 3 shows us that the drain to source resistance at Vgs of 2.5 V and 15 A is only about 0.009 Ω.  Nine Milliohm!

Using Ohm's law, 15 A over 9 mΩ drops only 0.135 V.

Depending on your other requirements, something like this could work.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have no clue how you found this but so far this seems perfect. First time ordering on digikey, hopefully it arrives soon and this fixes the problem. Was worried that I was missing something other than the Vgs being not low enough.

Comment: @robertkaras I don't know what the rest of your circuit looks like, so there is still room to mess it up! :-)  If it doesn't work, come on back and we'll get it sorted out.